# SQL Managed Instance Replication (Snapshot Agent) Timeouts

Tags: sql-server, transactional-replication

I have setup Transactional Replication on one of our Azure SQL Managed Instances, and I'm running into an issue with the Snapshot Agent.

It starts without any problems, gets to 84%, stalls and then displays this message.

> The process is running and is waiting for a response from the server.

While running, I noticed that the Snapshot Agent runs this select statement:

```
SELECT
SCHEMA_NAME(tbl.schema_id) AS [Table_Schema],
tbl.name AS [Table_Name],
i.name AS [Index_Name],
p.name AS [Name],
p.value AS [Value]
FROM
sys.tables AS tbl
INNER JOIN sys.indexes AS i ON (i.index_id > @_msparam_0 and i.is_hypothetical = @_msparam_1) AND (i.object_id=tbl.object_id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.key_constraints AS k ON k.parent_object_id = i.object_id AND k.unique_index_id = i.index_id
INNER JOIN sys.extended_properties AS p ON p.major_id=CASE (i.is_primary_key + 2*i.is_unique_constraint) WHEN 0 THEN i.object_id ELSE k.object_id END AND p.minor_id=CASE (i.is_primary_key + 2*i.is_unique_constraint) WHEN 0 THEN CAST(i.index_id AS int) ELSE 0 END AND p.class=CASE (i.is_primary_key + 2*i.is_unique_constraint) WHEN 0 THEN 7 ELSE 1 END
ORDER BY
[Table_Schema] ASC,[Table_Name] ASC,[Index_Name] ASC,[Name] ASC
```

When I execute this statement against the database manually, it never finishes. The statement completes almost instantly on any other database on the same instance.

Knowing that this database contains around 2000 tables and 41000 extended properties, I decided to execute the statement against another database in an on-prem instance which is substantially bigger (60k Tables and 1.2M Extended Properties) and it finishes almost instantly.

Has anyone encountered this issue before or have an idea about why this statement might be taking so long to finish?

EDIT: Using `sp_whoisactive`, the `wait_info` column is `NULL` and the `status` column is `runnable` and the statement is not being blocked by any other session.

Comment: I have added the edit as suggested (apologies, I should have added that in the first place). No blocking, no wait status and the task remains runnable for the entire duration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has now been resolved, after logging a support ticket with Microsoft.

If you try to replicate a database in a Managed Instances, which contains many Extended Properties, the Snapshot Agent suffers from timeout problems while it tries to load the Extended Properties into memory.

To work around this issue,

- Locate the Snapshot Agent Job
- Edit Step 2 labelled **Run agent**
- At the end of the Command, add `-PrefetchTables 0`
- Save the change

The Snapshot Agent will now work and will no longer time out.

Microsoft are aware of this problem, and will address it in a future build. No ETA on when that will be however.